# To register an event to an element before element is added to DOM?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

The element `#create_butt_1` does not do anything when being clicked. This only work when I call `setTimeout` before register the event to the element. Why this happens and what is another way to register the event to the element?

```
content = "<div class='no_content_div' id='brief_cal_no_cont_div'><p>There is no events</p><p class='create_butt create_new_task' id='create_butt_1'>create</p><div>";
$('#create_butt_1').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $addEventDialog = $('#add_event_dialog');
    showCenterDialog($addEventDialog);

}); 
$div.append(content);
```

Comment: is your event created after the page loads?

Comment: yes it is created after the page load

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to find `#create_button` on the page but, from your code it hasn't been appended yet.  Try creating the html in a fragment and then searching for the element within it, after that you can append it to the page:

```
content = $("<div class='no_content_div' id='brief_cal_no_cont_div'><p>There is no events</p><p class='create_butt create_new_task' id='create_butt_1'>create</p><div>");
$('#create_butt_1', content).click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $addEventDialog = $('#add_event_dialog');
    showCenterDialog($addEventDialog);
}); 
$div.append(content);
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mx3csebd/

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it to the DOM before you can register it for event listeners. Without seeing the rest of your code, I am assuming that `$div` is a reference to a `div` on your page, and you are using jQuery to append HTML to it.

If that's the case, you have to register the event *after* appending it to the `div` (and thereby adding it to the DOM), like this:

```
content = "<div class='no_content_div' id='brief_cal_no_cont_div'><p>There is no events</p><p class='create_butt create_new_task' id='create_butt_1'>create</p><div>";
$div.append(content);
$('#create_butt_1').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $addEventDialog = $('#add_event_dialog');
    showCenterDialog($addEventDialog);
});
```

```js
var $div = $("div");

var content = "<div class='no_content_div' id='brief_cal_no_cont_div'><p>There is no events</p><p class='create_butt create_new_task' id='create_butt_1'>create</p><div>";
$div.append(content);
$('#create_butt_1').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $addEventDialog = $('#add_event_dialog');
    showCenterDialog($addEventDialog);
});

function showCenterDialog(eventDialog){
    alert(JSON.stringify(eventDialog));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

---

An alternative (and better, in my opinion) way to do it would be to create actual HTML elements and register the event rather than use HTML strings:

```
var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
contentDiv.setAttribute("class", "no_content_div");
contentDiv.setAttribute("id", "brief_cal_no_cont_div");

var par1 = document.createElement("p");
par1.innerText = "There is no events";

var par2 = document.createElement("p");
par2.setAttribute("class", "create_butt create_new_task");
par2.setAttribute("id", "create_butt_1");
par2.innerText = "create";

par2.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $addEventDialog = $('#add_event_dialog');
    showCenterDialog($addEventDialog);
};

contentDiv.appendChild(par1);
contentDiv.appendChild(par2);
```

```js
var $div = $("div");

var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
contentDiv.setAttribute("class", "no_content_div");
contentDiv.setAttribute("id", "brief_cal_no_cont_div");

var par1 = document.createElement("p");
par1.innerText = "There is no events";

var par2 = document.createElement("p");
par2.setAttribute("class", "create_butt create_new_task");
par2.setAttribute("id", "create_butt_1");
par2.innerText = "create";

par2.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $addEventDialog = $('#add_event_dialog');
    showCenterDialog($addEventDialog);
};

contentDiv.appendChild(par1);
contentDiv.appendChild(par2);

$div.append(contentDiv);

function showCenterDialog(eventDialog){
    alert(JSON.stringify(eventDialog));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery functions like "delegate" or "on" for binding events to an element irrespective of element is present in DOM or not.
Here is the example

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#create_butt_1", function() {
   // Do something... 
});
```

Comment: I think click or on are the same?

Comment: No, If you write normal 'click', while compiling that line by browser the particular element should be present in the DOM. But when we use jQuery "on" function no need to present the element in the DOM, when ever the element added to DOM then event will bind to that element